# GAN Model Code Modification — 3 Channels to 1 Channel

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

This model is designed for processing 3-channel images (RGB) while I need to handle some black and white image data (grayscale), so I’d like to change the “ch” parameter to “1” instead of “3.”

The full code is available here — https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html

If we just change this parameter — “nc = 3” --> “nc = 1” — without adjusting generator’s and discriminator’s code blocks, executing just gives an error message:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 1, 4, 4], expected input[128, 3, 64, 64] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

Is there a guide on how to modify this or, perhaps, calculate these values manually using [this formula](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) (shape section)?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grayscale image is a "special case" of a color image: a pixel has a gray color iff the red channel equals the green equals the blue. Thus a pixel with values `[200, 10, 30]` will be green-ish in color, while a pixel with values `[180, 180, 180]` will have a gray color.
Therefore, the simplest way to process gray scale images using a pre-trained RGB model is to duplicate the single channel of the grayscale image 3 times to generate RGB-like image with three channels that has gray colors.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no easy workaround to just modify the existing model code from the tutorial to adjust it for grayscale image data?

Comment: @web_tracer you can. but it is not completely trivial. Moreover, if you want to use pre-trained weights - you need to manipulate the weights as well.

Comment: Copy that. Will try to dig deeper into this. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the dataset object creation and was brilliantly resolved [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dc-gan-modification-rgb-to-grayscale/128055/3).

So basically we need to replace this part:

```
# Create the dataset
dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=dataroot,
                           transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.Resize(image_size),
                               transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
                           ]))
```

With this one:

```
# Create the dataset
dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=dataroot,
                           transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.Resize(image_size),
                               transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                               transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize(0.5, 0.5),
                           ]))
```